# Design of API to accept multiple choices in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an interface/abstract class where the implementation can support an arbitrary sized dictionary of `Name`, `identifier`.  Each implementation will have a different format for `identifier` which is implementation specific.

The caller needs to retrieve the list of `Name`s from the provider and use those to ask the user which he cares about.  The user can select one or more.

I considered the following design where the caller gets an array of names and sets the user's choice by passing in an array of ints, identifying the array indicies of the names the user chose.

```
public abstract String[] GetNames();
public abstract void SetNamesToUse(int[] names);
```

Not happy with this, I also considered a model where a list of objects would be passed around:

```
public class NameObject {
    public bool SelectedByUser;
    public String Name;
    private String ProviderSpecificData;
}

...

public abstract List<NameObject> GetNames();
public abstract void SetNamesToUse(List<NameObject> names);
```

This seems cleaner and easier on the caller.

What other choices do I have? How have you solved similar?

Comment: @IanMercer My thinking was the provider needs to hold this list anyway, and that I might as well include the selector within it.  Your suggestion to use HastSet is a good one; I'll consider it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
interface IIdentifier
{
    string Name {get;}
}

abstract class Identifier<T> : IIdentifier
{
    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly T _id;
    public string Name {get;set;}

    protected Identifier(string name, T id)
    {
        _id = id;
        _name = name;
    }
}

class GuidIdentifier : Identifier<Guid>
{
    public GuidIdentifier(string name, Guid identifier)
        :base(name, identifier)
    {
        //?
    }
}

class UserOptions
{
    private IEnumerable<IIdentifier> _identifiers;

    public IEnumerable<IIdentifier> Identifiers {get {return _identifiers;}}

    public IIdentifier Selected {get;set;}

    public UserOptions(IEnumerable<IIdentifier> identifiers)
    {
        _identifiers = identifiers;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the consistency of your second example. It has nothing to do with the use of NameObject class or List<>. You can make your first example consistent too:

```
public abstract String[] GetNames();
public abstract void SetNamesToUse(String[] names);
```

To select all, you can now simply write

```
SetNamesToUse(GetNames());
```

In my experience, a single use case is not enough to choose from the many possible design options. If you write client code for more use cases, however, things start jumping out at you.

In my one-line example above, the GetNames() call looks ambiguous. Is it a call to get the names from the user or a call to get all the available names? A method name change can clarify this:

```
SetNamesToUse(GetAllNames());
```

Ferenc Mihaly 
http://theamiableapi.com